# Sending data to server in Node JS for downloading a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

So I am trying to send the data from the client to server and then at the server I am creating a new File and in the router I am sending back response to download that file.

But I could not achieve it. I am using AJAX call. Following is my code:

My Ajax call on clicking a button:

```
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/createDownloadFile',
      data: JSON Object,
    }).done(() => {
      window.open('/download');
    });
```

In express.js:

```
  app.post('/createDownloadFile', (req, res) => {
    downloadFile.createDownloadFile(req);
    res.send('SUCCESS');
  });
```

downloadFile in a JS below:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');


module.exports.createDownloadFile = (request) => {
  if (request) {
    let filePath;
    const userID = 'xyz';
    filePath = path.join(__dirname, userID.concat('.txt'));
    const dataToWrite = request.body;
    fs.openSync(filePath, 'w', (err) => {
      if (err) throw new Error('FILE_NOT_PRESENT');
    });
    fs.appendFileSync(filePath, JSON.stringify(dataToWrite, null, 4), (err) => {
    if (err) throw new Error('FILE_WRITE_ERROR');
     });
    return filePath;
  }
};
```

Also, in my router.js file:

```
  router.get('/download', (req, res) => {
    const filePath = makeDownloadFile.createDownloadFile(req);
    res.download(filePath);
  });
```

But seems like when I invoke the AJAX call it creates the file but unable to write in the file?

What I am missing?

Comment: or can I have other ways to achieve this.